# PyQt5. Read values of a table column or row without a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Can I read the values of an entire column or row in a table without iterating through them?
Now I do it with iteration:

```
def get_column_data(self, column):
    data = []
    for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
        data.append(self.tableWidget.item(i, column).text())
    return data
```

Wonder whether is it possible to do this more elegantly without loop?

Comment: no, that's the right way, why do you think a loop is not elegant? What is elegant for you? For me the for loop is simple and for my simplicity it is elegance

Comment: I mean maybe it is some property like  
data = tableWidget.column_data
and you can read column without iterating

Comment: no, it does not exist, you can check all the functions in: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget-members.html